# grep -c in Bash doesn't recognize parameter

Tags: bash, unix, grep

I have an output file, which looks something like this:

```
value1!value2@value3
value1!value2@value3
value1!value2@value3
```

I want to find out, with `grep`, how many times the `value2` appears, so I'm doing this:

```
n = grep -c 'value2' outputfile.tmp

if[$n!=6] ; then
```

but when I run it, the console says this:

```
`"-c: command not found"`
```

like it doesn't recognize the parameter.

Answer (score 2):

This should already choke on the assignment `n =` with a space: Bash parameter assignments can't have spaces. Secondly, to assign the output of a command to a parameter, you have to use [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution):

```
n=$(grep -c 'value2' outputfile.tmp)
```

Notice that this will tell you how many *lines* contain *at least one occurrence* of `value2`, and not the actual number of `value2`. Consider:

```
$ grep -c 'value2' <<< 'value2value2'
1
```

If you know that there will only be one `value2` per line (or you want to count lines), we're good. If you want to count occurrences, you have to use something like

```
n=$(grep -o 'value2' outputfile.tmp | wc -l)
```

`grep -o` prints each match on a separate line, and `wc -l` counts the lines.

Now, to check if the value of `$n` is unequal to six, you use a conditional. Unlike the assignments, this *must* have spaces.

The `!=` comparison is for string comparison; for integers, you should use `-ne` ("not equal"):

```
if [ "$n" -ne 6 ]; then
```

Instead of the test command `[ ]`, Bash has the more flexible `[[ ]]` conditional epxression:

```
if [[ "$n" -ne 6 ]]; then
```

where quoting isn't strictly necessary (but doesn't hurt!).

Or we can use an arithmetic expression:

```
if (( n != 6 )); then
```

where any parameter is evaluated without prepending `$`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enclose the command with $() to set it to a variable:

```
n=$(grep -c 'value2' outputfile.tmp)
```

This is a type of command substitution, see near the bottom of this page: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html